# Query 2 will run based on the Query1 output

Tags: ssis

The Execute SQL Task will provide us database list. Based on the list Query2 should run on all the database.

## Query1 result :

```
databasename1
databasename2 
databasename3
```

## Query 2:

### step 1

```
select * from databasename1.dbo.tablename
```

### step 2

```
select * from databasename2.dbo.tablename
```

### step 3

```
select * from databasename3.dbo.tablename
```

How can I use the results of a query to power subsequent queries? In my case, change the catalog name,

Comment: Do you have a fixed databasename count or it will be a variable like may increase or decrease?

Comment: count are not fixed, i would vary all the time(daily).

Comment: you can create the output as your variable from store procedure as a string concatenated with database name separated by comma and using parameter mapping in SSIS will give you the output in SSIS variable

Comment: Further you can use that variable in foreach loop container and execute formed query using the database name after split functionality.

Comment: I have tried calling the SP Exec SP_Call_Production ? but its not working. Error :  "Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a `Foreach Loop Container`.

**You'll need the following control flow:**

`Execute SQL Task -> Foreach Loop Container` and another `Execute SQL Task` inside the container.

**You'll need two variables:**

- DatabaseList (Object)
- DatabaseName (String)

**List the databases with a SQL Task**

- Create a user variable with `Object` type (DatabaseList)
- On the `General` pane, set the `ResultSet` property to `Full result set`
- On the `Result Set` pane set the add a new line (`Result Name = 0, Variable Name = User::DatabaseList`)

This will query the databases and stores the list in an object.

**Note** There should be one database name in one record in the first `Execute SQL Task`'s query. Each record will be processed by the Foreach Loop.

**Add a `Foreach Loop Container` after the `SQL Command Task`**

- On the `Collection` pane set the `Enumerator` to `Foreach ADO Enumerator`
- Select `User::DatabaseList` as the `ADO object source variable`
- On the `Variable Mappings` pane add a new entry (`Variable = User::DatabaseName, Index = 0`)

**Add an `Execute SQL Task` inside the `Foreach Loop Container`** and set up as normally.

- Set the `ResultSet` property to `None` on the `General` pane.
- Copy the Query to the clipoard.

**Highlight the SQL Task inside the Container, then press F4** (opens the property tab).

Add a new expression which sets the `SqlStatementSource` property. As the Expression add an expression which returns the query with the database (based on the User::DatabaseName).

You can use expressions to dynamically set some the properties of an object. (This method also works with a `Data Flow Task` just the property to set (with the expression) could be different)

**Note** If you want to use DFT, then the tables should have the same structure (the meta data of the columns returned by the query should be the same in SSIS)

Comment: I have done all the steps. when i click on execute **Error:** The result binding name must be set to zero for full result set and XML results.

Comment: Which SQL Task throws this error? If the inner one, then set the ResulSet property on the General pane to 'None'

Comment: Ohh, I got it: in the first SQL Task, in the `Result Set` pane: `Result Name = 0, Variable Name = User::DatabaseList`

Comment: I have done that and how can i pass the variable in the final query. Is this the right way Exec SP_Call_Production ?

Comment: If the ? is the database name, then yes, but in this case you do not have to use expressions since you can pass the parameter without it. (Add the parameter in the `Parameter Maping` pane (Variable Name = User::DatabaseName, Direction = Input, Data Type = NVARCHAR, Parameter Name = 0, Parameter Size = -1 OR 128)

Comment: Perfect explaination @Pred

Comment: @Pred This is my first post in SSIS. Thanks for your Support and solution.